# UITableView with multiple Sections with multiple rows. I need sections to behave independently

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

UITableView with multiple Sections with multiple rows. All rows have checkmark accessory added & I need each section to behave differently. One section to allow just 1 checkmark to be selected while the other allow multiple selections. So at the moment my first section allows just 1 row to be selected. When another row in that section is selected it deselects the other.

In my second section the user can select multiple options which is also working HOWEVER this is where my issue is. When I select a row in "section 2" it deselects the option selected in "section 1". I am using a bunch of switch statements trying to get this to work but it feels there must be a simpler way. Any ideas? (please find code below)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let sectionNumber = indexPath.section
          switch sectionNumber {
          case 0:

            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark


          case 1:
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
                if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                    cell.accessoryType = .none
                } else {
                    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                }
            }

          case 2:
           if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
               if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                   cell.accessoryType = .none
               } else {
                   cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
               }
           }

            case 3:
             if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
                 if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                     cell.accessoryType = .none
                 } else {
                     cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                 }
             }


          default:
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

          }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let sectionNumber = indexPath.section
            let rowNumber = indexPath.row


        switch sectionNumber {
        case 0:
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        case 1:break
        case 2: break
          case 3:break
        default:break

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```swift
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Then you can just deselect the selected rows in section 0:

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            for selectedIndexPath in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? [] where selectedIndexPath.section == 0 {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: true)
                tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }

        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most significant issue in your code is that the changes in `didSelectRowAt` are not persistent. When the user scrolls you'll get unexpected behavior because cells are reused.

You have to add a property in your model to maintain the state of the selection for example

```
var isSelected = false
```

In the controller declare a property to save the selected index path for the single selection section

```
var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath?
```

In `cellForRowAt` set the state of the accessory type depending on the `isSelected` property

```
let item = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
```

In `didSelectRowAt` in section 0 deselect the row at `selectedIndexPath` and selected the current row, and you have to consider the case to deselect the current row. In the other sections toggle `isSelected`. It's important to change the model and then reload the affected rows which calls `cellForRowAt` and updates the cells.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            if let selectedPath = selectedIndexPath {
                if selectedPath == indexPath { // The current row is already selected: Deselected the row
                   sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].isSelected = false
                   selectedIndexPath = nil
                   tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
                } else { // Select the current row and deselect the row at `selectedIndexPath` 
                    sections[selectedIndexPath.section][selectedIndexPath.row].isSelected = false
                    sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].isSelected = true
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath, selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
                    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
                }
            } else { // nothing is selected: Select the row
                sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].isSelected = true
                selectedIndexPath = indexPath
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
            }
        default: // toggle the selection
            sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for that, you can use the builtin `UITableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows`.

Answer (score 0):

> In my second section the user can select multiple options which is also working HOWEVER this is where my issue is. When I select a row in "section 2" it deselects the option selected in "section 1". I am using a bunch of switch statements trying to get this to work but it feels there must be a simpler way. Any ideas?

The big mistake you seem to be making here is that you're relying on the table cells to store data. Whether a given row in your table has a check mark or not should be a feature of your data model, not a setting in a table cell. You're not letting the user check certain rows because it looks nice -- the check mark should *mean* something, and that meaning should be captured in your data.

I think that the reason people run into this problem is that they start the app development process by thinking about how the app should look, and so they begin by creating the user interface without giving any thought to how the data should be modeled. They store data in generic structures like an array or dictionary of dictionaries so that they can get something working quickly, and they end up with a ton of code in their view controller that tries to enforce behaviors that would come naturally if they thought in terms of business rules instead of user interface actions. Just look at the language you're using: you're talking about how many rows can be selected in which section instead of more natural rules about the data that your app is dealing with.

To solve the problem, you need to change your perspective. Stop writing UI code for a bit and focus on your data. Your goal is to build a model class that will manage all the data and rules that govern that data -- you're creating the M in MVC. Sit down and just write out the content and rules for your data. Then implement your model, and let that implementation drive the table's behavior. If you can only have one row selected in the first section of your table, it should be because your model enforces a rule like "every customer has exactly one sales contact." The table view and view controller shouldn't know or care about the "only one selected" requirement -- it's just a feature of the model. If you select a different row in the first section, that should result in a different sales contact being selected in the model, and since the model enforces the "only one" rule, the model will deselect the previous sales contact. The nice thing about that is that you can then change business rules in the model -- maybe allow up to *three* sales contacts per customer -- and you don't have to do anything to the table or the view controller.